Under what condition do the CrowdStrike exfiltration tools capture a Virtual Machine's shared clipboard?
When I work remotely, I have a VM set up which I used to RDP into my work machine. This VM has a shared clipboard enabled, i.e. I can copy and paste to and from the VM host, which in turn can copy and paste to and from the remotely connected computer.
Specifically the VM Host is Windows 10 running Hyper-V, the VM is Windows 10, the remote computer is Windows 10, and the VM is connected to the remote computer via Windows RDP.
I notice that one of the processes on my work machine from CrowdStrike is a clipboard monitor, and in their data exfiltration monitoring they explicitly mention they can record clipboard contents.  So I am assuming the clipboard data is at least being analysed, if not outright logged.
I often leave this VM minimised and stay connected to my work PC all day, even outside of work hours. The way Windows' shared clipboard works, I am wondering what data from the VM host is potentially available to CrowdStrike to monitor (*for example, does it always copy host clipboard data to the VM as soon as it is copied, or does it pull from the host when data is pasted), and in practice what it actually monitors.

Ok, some real questions now: What is the VM hypervisor? What OS are the host and VM client? What OS is the work machine? Is it a real Microsoft RDP session or are you using third party software? Need to know all of the software involved in the "chain" to answer this.

@Romen I have added more details

I unfortunately can't answer the question with confidence, but I'm like 80% sure that the clipboard sharing between host/VM and VM/Work is event based, i.e. Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are the trigger that moves data between the systems and only when those clipboard actions happen. The most recent thing you pasted on the work machine may be what the CrowdStrike monitoring process gets to see.
